# calling a servlet from html table row and get response in that row

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a requirement in my project architecture that I have to call a servlet from html table row and when the servlet send response the response should be shown in that html row.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`jsp:include`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref1112.html) in your table.

```
<jsp:include page="/HandlerServlet" flush="true">
```

*But it doesn't lead to good design.*

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with Ajax. Have a look at jQuery library that makes it easy.

Or you can use a library like Ext-JS that would give you a grid (table) that fetches data from servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org). It's simple to use.